# Is possible to avoid or warn overriding a method or property of an inherited class on TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to avoid this:

```
class a {
    p:any;
    constructor() {
    }
    m() {
    }
}
class b extends a {
    p:any;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    m() {
    }
}
```

I know that I can create private properties, but to access them externally I need to create a public method, so the problem is still there, as methods are "overridable" without any warning, but I don't find any options to avoid that.

I can also create setters and getters, but the same applies.

Comment: Why are you trying to prevent this? Bear in mind that it would make your testing more difficult, as you won't be able to inherit and mock methods as easily.

Comment: because I'm creating a set of libraries for npm and accidentally have overwritten a crucial property... :-(

Comment: Ops, forgot to quote. @ssube

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Maybe there's something that I don't know, like being able to override but adding a tag before overriding or you get a warning or something like that. It will be still able to override, but knowing that is actually overriding something, not by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to have `final` methods (methods that subclasses are forbidden from overriding). This feature has [been](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9264) [requested](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306) of TypeScript, but as of the time of writing: it's not being accepted.

Comment: Great. Checked the issues page just in case but found nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's the idea behind object oriented programming...

Notice that if you change the types then you get compilation errors:

```
class A {
    p: string;
}

class B extends A {
    p: number;
}
```

You get:

> Class 'b' incorrectly extends base class 'a'.
>   Types of property 'p' are incompatible.
>   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

And the same with methods:

```
class A {
    m(): string {
        return null;
    }
}

class B extends a {
    m(): number {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Produces:

> Class 'b' incorrectly extends base class 'a'.
>   Types of property 'm' are incompatible.
>   Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
>   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

---

#### Edit

You can't really override properties.
Take this code for example:

```
class A {
    a: string;

    constructor() {
        this.a = "default";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    a: string;

    setA(value: string) {
        this.a = value;
    }
}
```

It seems that you're overriding the property when you declare it on `B`, but if you look at the compiled js:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.a = "default";
    }
    return A;
}());
var B = (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    B.prototype.setA = function (value) {
        this.a = value;
    };
    return B;
}(A));
```

The property `a` isn't defined before it's assigned.

You can argue that the compiler should warn you for redefining an existing property, but then you won't be able to do this:

```
interface X {
    str: string;
}

interface Y extends X {
    num: number;
}

class A {
    a: X;
}

class B extends A {
    a: Y;
}
```

Also, when it comes to methods, IDEs should show you when you are overriding a method, at least webstorm shows an icon in the left tray.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but, what if I actually override with the same type?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Hm, nice edit. The closest thing I can get right now. EDIT: Just noticed the other answer. More appropriate. Btw, good answer. Going to upvote it as right now is the closest thing to what I want achieve.